# Can't get localStorage to display output on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

This is a practice exercise (prior to entry into bootcamp) that is a list of favorite things entered in by the user. LocalStorage works in saving and deleting properly, up to the point of refresh, where the entire list disappears. But after another entry, the entire list then loads; it just doesn't hang around after refresh. For the life of me, I can't figure out why.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 stuff">
      <h3><i>Enter in a favorite thing, then hit the button</i></h3>

<!-- form -->
      <form id="the-form">
        <input id="list-input" type="text" placeholder="sexy time" size="40">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <hr>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /col-sm-12 -->
  </div> <!-- /row -->

<!-- results -->
  <div class="row">
    <div id="show" class="col-sm-7">
      <h3 class="fav-things">My most favoritest things</h3>

      <ul id="list-items">
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div> <!-- /row -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list-items").html(localStorage.getItem("listItems")); // refresh not working

    $("#the-form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var item = $("#list-input").val();

        if (item) {
            $("#list-items").append("<li>" + item + "<a href='#' class='delete'>x</a><hr></li>");
            $("#show").show();
        }
        localStorage.setItem("listItems", $("#list-items").html()); // saves input to localStorage
        $("#list-input").val("");  // removes value from input
    });

  // Remove List item
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function() { // .on() to work with dynamic element <li>
        $(this).parent().slideUp(300, function() { // grabbing the parent of the x that was clicked on
            $(this).remove();  // removing the parent of the clicked on x
            localStorage.setItem("listItems", $("#list-items").html());  // saves input to localStorage
        });
    });
});
```

CSS - I forgot to add the CSS, which has the results initially hidden with  #show { display: none; }

```
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.stuff {
  background-color: #ffe5ff;
  border: 1px solid #ffe5ff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#list-input {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#show {
  display: none;
  background-color: #e5ffff;
  border: 1px solid #99ddff;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.delete {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

hr {
  width: 80%;
}

.fav-things {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d9d9d9;
}
```

Comment: When you say refresh you are talking about click refresh on the browser?

Comment: Works for me. Copied, pasted into a document, worked just fine.

Comment: Looks like jsFiddle lets us use localStorage, so: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/d54brcrz/).

Comment: yes, It seems that everything works fine

Comment: I think you might be running into this if you run it offline or online.

Comment: its working fine for me too. And there seems nothing wrong with the code too.

Comment: @VartanArabyan - Yes, on refreshing browser I don't get the results to show for some reason. Yet, everyone here is saying it works fine. Yet, when I refresh, the list items all disappear. I forgot to add that CSS starts off with #show {display: none; So the results are initially hidden.

Comment: @Padawan What is the format of your URL in the browser? You can anonymize individual words, but I'd like to see the format, especially whether it starts with `http` or `file://`

Comment: @Katana314 - file:///Users/Padawan/Dropbox/folder/folder_2/JavaScript/23_JQ_code_review/index.html?#

Answer (score 1):

`file:///Users/Padawan/Dropbox/folder/folder_2/JavaScript/23_JQ_code_review/index‌​.html?#`

That would explain it. You need to try viewing your project from a small "web server" - then your browser can connect to "`http://localhost`" or "`http://localhost:1234`" (port number) to view your project. One of the easier ones to set up is "XAMPP". You could look around for others, many of which would be more complicated than you need. An appropriate google search would be "free basic web server".

Comment: Well, I've been able to do this before, working with localStorage since, it's  storing in the browser. When I completed the course on OneMonth.com we did the same thing where we saved to localStorage, deleted from it and .getItem() on refresh on the onset. If what you say is true I guess I don't understand the disconnect since, from my understanding, the whole concept of localStorage is for the user to interact with the app and the browser saves the input.

Comment: Using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` may be even easier, if you have python installed

Comment: @Padawan If your course had you either working on an interactive HTML/JS page that was on a public domain, or using some other program to make your localStorage, it would work normally. But `localStorage` is domain-specific, and browsers don't really have any idea how to associate it if it's being opened from `file://`. Thankfully, `localhost` counts as a domain. jbmartinez's suggestion could work as well.

Comment: @Katana314 - k, the course had me working on my own files. But, I'll look into the XAMPP, and I'm not up on Python. Thanks for your time.